# recv(MSG_PEEK) timeout

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I have a socket where I set a timeout for `recv()`.
I have two steps for `recv()`, first I check content of received data if complete using `MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT`.

```
recvTimeout.tv_sec = mRecvTimeoutSecs;
recvTimeout.tv_usec = mRecvTimeoutUSecs; 
sendTimeout.tv_sec = mSendTimeoutSecs;
sendTimeout.tv_usec = mSendTimeoutUSecs;

result = enableSocketOption(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &recvTimeout, sizeof(recvTimeout));

peekdLen = ::recv(mSocket, peekDataBuffer, MAX_RECV_LENGTH, MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

I'm just thinking if `recv()` will timeout if I used `MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the socket will not timeout, as `MSG_DONTWAIT` will cause `recv()` to return immediately. Note that if you set like 1 msec timeout, then it might timeout - that would depend on the implementation (on which OS your code runs on).

Comment: if i remove 'MSG_DONTWAIT' flag.. will it timeout in ::recv(MSG_PEEK) ?

Comment: Yes. All that `MSG_PEEK` does is that it does not mark the received data as read - so there is no difference in behavior to a call without it, except that the data is not moved out from the socket. So yes, if there is no data in the socket, it will wait for some to arrive. See [docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html). You can also try it yourself - open one socket, connect to it and try when it times out and when it does not (no need to create another thread or anything, just open a socket above your code and connect to `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: ah, i need recv() timeout, so i will remove 'MSG_DONTWAIT'. thank you! :)